# Transforming analog keypresses to digital

Tags: python, keypress, joystick, analog-digital-converter

In python I want to simulate a joystick that when used, to give values between -63 and +63 let's say. When the value it's positive, I want to press the "w" key and "s" key when negative.
I am not having problems receiving the values, but to transform these analog values into digital key presses. Does anyone has any idea how to do it (code can be in any language, I just need an general idea).

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you have an actual joystick and you want to send key presses to the program, or do you want to take key presses and use them to generate a value from -63 to +63?

Comment: Yes, the joystick's position is taken and instead of giving it a value between 1.0 and -1.0 he gives values between -63 and +63, and i need to convert these values into keypresses (for example in a racing game, when the y axis is max, the key is continuously being pressed, but when the axis is at the half of positive value, the key should be pressed in a way that the vehicle speeds up half of the max value - the key being pressed only half of the time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PostMessage with the WM_CHAR command (if you're using Windows - you didn't say).